# Two Phase Commit with IEnlistmentNotification interface

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

When Commit is called (for the implementation of IEnlistmentNotification) can I just throw an exception to indicate I want the transaction to rollback?

Comment: After `Commit` is called it is too late for rollbacks.

Comment: Actually, no - until Enlistment.Done() is called in the implementation instance, there is still a chance to rollback!

Comment: Was my answer not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should instead call [Transaction.Rollback(Exception ex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149788%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
   public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
   {
      Transaction currentTx = Transaction.Current;
      if (currentTx != null)
      {
         currentTx.RollBack(new Exception("I give up!");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Based on my test code it seems that Transaction.Current is always null when Commit() method is called. Any ideas?